# Which kind of service will be the best to store data and calculate sth (injected to controller) between requests?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, web-applications, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm the new in web development. I undestend every kind of dependency injestion: scoped, transient, singleton, but no one meets my expectations. My controller is required to calculate arithmetic average, so I send GET request with next number to calculate avg. So, I need service (injected to controller) to store these numbers and calculate the avg every request.

If I use transient, new instance of service will be created, so I can't store actual sum of values. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: What kind of application is it? MVC? Rest/WebApi? For MVC see [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Rest/WebAPI is supposed to be stateless so using session is a no-go

Comment: Exactly, is it WebApi

Answer (score 0):

In order to store the previous numbers (or last result with weigt) you can use the cookies directly, or you can use tempdata. https://learn.microsoft.com/ens/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata
I would not dismiss the session mechanism unless you have multiple instances.